# On a multi-select form, on submit select all options if none were selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multi-select

Using jQuery/Javascript, when a user clicks submit I need to validate if at least one option has been chosen on a select form, and one hasn't been chosen, I need them all to be submitted.

So on a form like this:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" id="carfare" name="mycarform">
<select name="car" id="carchoice" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input id="carsubmit" type="submit">
</form>
```

If the user clicks the submit button without choosing any options, I need it to return:
http://example.com/?car=volvo&car=saab&car=opel&car=audi

Comment: Just an idea, alternatively you could check to see if the `car` parameter is empty in your php script that processes the form, and if it is you can use all the options then

Comment: why not just have all options selected by default, or use checkboxes?

Comment: I can't change the script that processes the form, so I need the data selected before the submit.

Comment: And, yes, I could have them all selected by default, but that requires more interaction from a user who wants to make specific selections: they have to unselect all and then select their choices (the actually form I'm working with has quite a few options). I'd much rather have the fall-back be virtually transparent to the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if there are any items selected by doing

```
if(!$('#carchoice').val())
```

then, set them all selected by

```
$('#carchoice option').prop("selected", true);
```

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
   if(!$('#carchoice').val()){
     $('#carchoice option').prop("selected", true);
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" id="carfare" name="mycarform">
<select name="car" id="carchoice" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input id="carsubmit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit check if option is selected, if not select all.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#carefare').submit( function () {
        var choice = $('#carchoice').val();
        if(!choice) {
            $('#carchoice option').attr('selected','selected');
        }
    });
});
```

refer **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05ufysgw/)**
check network tab for submitted values